# Dynamic property query in handlebars

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, mustache, express-handlebars

I am trying to get a property of an object in handlebars dynamically dependent upon the `pid` that the `#each` loop is currently on. I have tried the following code but the value isn't getting populated at all. I'm imagining there's some sort of context problem, but as I'm quite new to handlebars, I don't know the way to go about doing this.

```html
<div class="card-deck">
        {{#each entries}}
                {{! backend only hidden comments}}
                <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="/userimgres/{{pid}}/0.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title"><strong>{{name}}</strong></h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{desc}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                                <small class="text-muted">Posted {{../ago.[pid]}} ago (ID: {{pid}})</small>
                        </div>
                </div>
        {{/each}}
</div>
```

My `ago` object is setup with the key as the `pid` and the value as a string describing, in human readable format, how long it's been since a specified date/time.
For what it's worth, it's generated by a separate function from a constant object, hence why it's not in the same object to begin with. It looks like this:

```js
{
  '1000': '2 hours ago',
  '1001': 'a month ago',
  '1002': '3 days ago',
  '2000': '4 days ago',
  '2001': '12 days ago',
  '2002': '4 months ago',
  '2003': 'a month ago'
}
```

When I change the code to be static and query `{{../ago.[1001]}}`, I receive my string for that specific ID. Since the code relies on a for each, however, this obviously returns the same exact string for the other entries.

How can I modify this statement to dynamically query the `ago` object for a key's value - the key being defined by the `pid` that is currently being iterated through in the `#each` (i.e. what I'm doing elsewhere in this codeblock by simply calling `{{pid}}`)?

I have tried `{{../ago.[{{pid}}]}}` and several other arrangements but none seem to work.
Many thanks in advance for any help, and I'm happy to clear anything up if this is unclear.

Comment: The linked documentation to the lookup helper there got me where I needed to be. Thanks! I'll answer my own question in case anyone stumbles across this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the lookup helper as [documented here](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup)

From the docs:

> The lookup helper allows for dynamic parameter resolution using Handlebars variables.
>   This is useful for resolving values for array indexes.
>
> ````
> {{#each people}}
>   {{.}} lives in {{lookup ../cities @index}}
> {{/each}}```
> ````

In the instance of this question, you can simply change this example from using the current index to use a variable (in this case `pid`) located in the same context that the `#each` loop is in.

**`{{lookup ../ago pid}}` should work for you. It gets the object `ago` from the parent context, then based off the `#each` loop's current iteration of `entries.pid`, it gets the value from `../pid` for the key of `pid` it's on.**

In other situations, you may need to continue reading the documentation linked in this answer for other ways of using the `locate` helper:

> It can also be used to lookup properties of object based on data from the input. The following is a more complex example that uses lookup in a sub-expression to change the evaluation context to another object based on a property-value.
>
> ```
> {{#each persons as | person |}}
>   {{name}} lives in {{#with (lookup ../cities [resident-in])~}}
>     {{name}} ({{country}})
>   {{/with}}
> {{/each}}
> ```